# How to check if the computer can connect to Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am testing an application that is getting the display name of the user logged in on a computer part of an Active Directory like so:

```
var systemUserName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

The problem is when I am using the same computer out of the Active Directory Network, because I get an exception and the application crashes:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: 'The server could not be contacted.'
```

Is there a way to check if the computer is first connected to the AD?

Comment: Is your application need to be accessed outside network/VPN?

Comment: Yes if I am not working at the office or VPN is down.

Comment: So, what do you think how the AD would be known to outside network?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question. It won't be known, I guess (null)?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4390226b-3286-4695-991e-e37a374c3ff4/how-do-you-access-windows-server-domain-outside-the-network?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Let me know if these links are helpful, they are not talking about your exact situation but there would be a proper way through which we consume AD information from outside domain.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212138/how-do-i-authenticate-against-active-directory-from-asp-net-web-service-code

Comment: @MihaiDumitru - As an alternate suggestion, the current exception should be catched in your application citing the reason that the AD DC can't be contacted!